# Calculate a custom time object with other objects of same class (operator overloading)

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am creating a program for keeping track of finishing times in a sports competition (skiing, running etc.) with interval starts. The program asks the user when the first competitor started, and what sort of intervals the competitors use (30 seconds og 60 seconds).

I am trying to calculate the time used in the race for each competitor by subtracting the starting time from the finish time (since they all have different starting times), but I can't seem to get it working. It registers the correct start and finish time for each competitor, but the time elapsed object (which I calculate with "elapsed = finish - start" inside the Competitor constructor) is just set to 00:00:00.

Can anyone see what I have done wrong? Something wrong with my overloaded operators?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include "timer.h"
using namespace std;

const int MAX_NAME = 30;                        // Maks. lengde på navn/nasjonalitet
const int MAX_COMPS = 20;                       // Antall utøvere
const int MAX_LINE = 60;                        // Length of line + '/0'

class Time
    {
    private:
        int hh,
            mm,
            ss;
    public:
        Time()
            { hh = mm = ss = 0; }
        Time(int h, int m, int s)
            { hh = h; mm = m; ss = s; }
        Time operator + (Time t);
        Time operator - (Time t);
        bool operator < (Time t);
        Time operator * (int n);
        void showTime();

    };

class Competitor
    {
    private:
        int startNumber;
        char name[MAX_NAME + 1];
        char nationality[MAX_NAME + 1];
        Time start;
        Time finish;
        Time sinceStart = finish - start;
    public:
        Competitor()
            {
            startNumber = 0;
            strcpy_s(name, "");
            strcpy_s(nationality, "");
            }
        Competitor(int n, char nm[], char nt[], Time calcStart);
        void showCompetitor();
        void setCompetitor(char buffer[], int n);
        void setFinish(int h, int m, int s);
    };

void menu();
void readFromFile();
void showAllCompetitors();
Time setInterval();
void registerFinish();
int read(char text[], int one, int two);
char read();

Competitor competitors[MAX_COMPS];                  // Array med plass til MAX_COMPS løpere

int lastCompetitor = 0;                             // Holder styr på antall løpere
Time compStart,
     interval;

// MAIN-FUNKSJON
int main()
    {
    int startH,
        startM;
    char choice;

    interval = setInterval();

    cout << "\nEnter start Time for the first competitor (HH MM): ";
    cin >> startH >> startM; compStart = Time(startH, startM, 0);

    readFromFile();             // Løpere leses inn fra fil og legges i løper-array

    menu();
    cout << "\nEnter choice: "; choice = read();
    while(choice != 'Q')
        {
        switch(choice)
            {
                case 'R':
                    registerFinish();
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    showAllCompetitors();
                    break;
                case 'W':
                    // Lag funksjon som skriver resultater til fil
                    // break;
                default:
                    menu();
                    break;
            }
        cout << "\nEnter choice: "; choice = read();
        }

    competitors[1].showCompetitor();

    cout << endl << endl;



    return 0;
    }

// KLASSE-FUNKSJONSDEFINISJONER
void Competitor::setCompetitor(char buffer[], int n)
    {
    startNumber = n;
    strncpy_s(name, buffer, MAX_NAME);
    strncpy_s(nationality, buffer + 30, MAX_NAME);
    }

void Competitor::showCompetitor()
    {
    cout << startNumber << ". " << name << " (" << nationality << ")";
    cout << "\nStarted: "; start.showTime();
    cout << "\nFinished: "; finish.showTime();
    cout << "\nTime used: "; sinceStart.showTime();
    }

Competitor::Competitor(int n, char nm[], char nt[], Time calcStart)
    {
    startNumber = n;
    strncpy_s(name, nm, MAX_NAME);
    strncpy_s(nationality, nt, MAX_NAME);
    start = compStart + interval * (startNumber - 1);
    }

void Competitor::setFinish(int h, int m, int s)
    { finish = Time(h, m, s); }

Time Time::operator + (Time t)
    {
    int totalSecs,
        totalSecs2,
        diffSecs;
    Time elapsed;
    totalSecs = hh * 3600 + mm * 60 + ss;                   // Objekt-tidspunkt i sekunder.
    totalSecs2 = t.hh * 3600 + t.mm * 60 + t.ss;            // Starttidspunkt for løp i sek.
    diffSecs = totalSecs + totalSecs2;                      // Differanse mellom starttidspunkt og objekt-tidspunkt i sek.

    elapsed.hh = diffSecs / 3600;
    elapsed.mm = (diffSecs % 3600) / 60;
    elapsed.ss = (diffSecs % 60);

    return elapsed;
    }

Time Time::operator - (Time t)
    {
    int totalSecs,
        totalSecs2,
        diffSecs;
    Time diff;
    totalSecs = hh * 3600 + mm * 60 + ss;
    totalSecs2 = t.hh * 3600 + t.mm * 60 + t.ss;
    diffSecs = totalSecs2 - totalSecs;

    diff.hh = diffSecs / 3600;
    diff.mm = (diffSecs % 3600) / 60;
    diff.ss = (diffSecs % 60);

    return diff;
    }

bool Time::operator < (Time t)
    {
    int totalSecs,
        totalSecs2;
    totalSecs = hh * 3600 + mm * 60 + ss;
    totalSecs2 = t.hh * 3600 + t.mm * 60 + t.ss;
    if(totalSecs < totalSecs2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }

Time Time::operator * (int n)
    {
    int totalSec;                   // Gjør om Tid intervall til en int med 30/60
    Time secToTime;                 // Tiden siden start for hver enkelt løper

    totalSec = (hh * 3600 + mm * 60 + ss) * n;      // Multipliserer intervall-tid med startnummer-1
    secToTime.hh = totalSec / 3600;
    secToTime.mm = (totalSec % 3600) / 60;
    secToTime.ss = (totalSec % 60);
    return secToTime;               // Returnerer Tid-objekt med tid siden løpets start
    }

void Time::showTime()
    {
    cout << " " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hh << ":"
        << setw(2) << setfill('0') << mm << ":"
        << setw(2) << setfill('0') << ss;
    }

// ANDRE FUNKSJONSDEFINISJONER
void menu()
    {
    cout << "\nR - Register a new finish";
    cout << "\nD - Displays the current list of finished competitors";
    cout << "\nW - Write results to file";
    cout << "\nQ - Quit program";
    cout << endl;
    }

void readFromFile()
    {
    ifstream infile("COMPETITORS.DTA");
    int count = 1;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    char nat[MAX_NAME];
    Time calcStart;

    if(infile)
        {
        infile.getline(name, MAX_NAME);
        infile.getline(nat, MAX_NAME);
        competitors[count] = Competitor(count, name, nat, calcStart);
        while(infile)
            {
            ++lastCompetitor;
            infile.getline(name, MAX_NAME);
            infile.getline(nat, MAX_NAME);
            competitors[++count] = Competitor(count, name, nat, calcStart);
            }
        }
    }

void showAllCompetitors()
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < lastCompetitor; i++)
        {
        competitors[i+1].showCompetitor();
        cout << endl;
        }
    }

Time setInterval()
    {
    int choice;
    cout << "\nEnter interval between competitors\n\t1. 30 seconds\n\t2. 60 seconds";
    choice = read("Choice", 1, 2);
    if(choice == 1)
        return Time(0, 0, 30);
    else
        return Time(0, 1, 0);
    }

void registerFinish()
    {
    Timer t;
    int n,
        h,
        m,
        s;
    n = read("\nEnter start number", 1, lastCompetitor);
    t.hent(h, m, s);
    competitors[n].setFinish(h, m, s);
    }

int read(char text[], int one, int two)
    {
    int n;
    do
        {
        cout << endl << text << " (" << one << " - " << two << "): ";
        cin >> n;
        } while(n < one || n > two);
    return n;
    }

char read()
    {
    char ch;
    cin >> ch; cin.ignore();
    return (toupper(ch));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a member for calculating sinceStart:

```
class Competitor
    {
    private:
        int startNumber;
        char name[MAX_NAME + 1];
        char nationality[MAX_NAME + 1];
        Time start;
        Time finish;
        Time sinceStart() const {return finish - start;}
    public:
        Competitor()
            {
            startNumber = 0;
            strcpy_s(name, "");
            strcpy_s(nationality, "");
            }
        Competitor(int n, char nm[], char nt[], Time calcStart);
        void showCompetitor();
        void setCompetitor(char buffer[], int n);
        void setFinish(int h, int m, int s);
    };
```

Comment: Isn't it allowed to assign the object like I had done?

Comment: It is better to not keep a redundant variable like sinceStart. Your initialization does not mean sinceStart will be updated to be equal to finish - start. It seems you do not update sinceStart in setFinish (which could be an alternative, but worse, solution).